# Problems with server-side string validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, webforms, boolean

I am developing a custom class to contain regular expressions. The reason is that I had a lot of problems with client-side expressions not always validating on postback.

The class I am writing has an input of the text and will return true depending on that particular test.

I am trying to do an expression to check that the string only contains numbers and return true if it does, otherwise if it contains anything else it should return false.

The regular expression I am entering is throwing an error: Unrecognized escape sequence and won't run.

This is the method:

```
static public bool IsOnlyNumeric(string InputText)
{
    //Returns true if only numeric
    bool val = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(InputText, "[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*");

    return val;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the back slash `\`.

```
"[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*"
//     ^^ double backslash
```

This is because the backslash is what you use to escape other characters. To escape it, you need to prefix it with another one.

The alternative is to use a verbatim string literal by prefixing the string with an `@`:

```
@"[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below menioned code

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(inputtext, "^[0-9]*$")
```

Answer (score -1):

To handle the numeric only data without decimal change the code as follows:

```
static public bool IsOnlyNumeric(string InputText)
{
    //Returns true if only numeric
    bool val = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(InputText, "^[1-9]\d*$");

    return val;

}
```

Comment: I have the same error and it is highlighted on the 'd' character of your expression.